# How to check template class method return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I try to check in Class2 return return value type of method getGG() of class given as template parameter but my code doesn't compile. How to do it properly?

```
template <class T, class U>
struct hasProperMethodReturnValueType {
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<T, std::decltype(U.getGG())>;
};

template<class P> class Class1 {
private:
    P gg;
public: 
    Class1(P a) : gg(a) {} 
    P getGG() {
        return gg;
    }   
};

template<class A, class P> class Class3 {
private:
    P gg;
    A dd;
public: 
    Class3(P a, A r) : gg(a), dd(r) {} 
    P getGG() {
        return gg;
    }   
};

template<class G, class R> class Class2 {
    static_assert(hasProperMethodReturnValueType<G, R>::value, "Not same type");
private:
    R cc;
public:
    Class2(R r) : cc(r) {};
};

int main() {
    auto obj  = Class2<int, Class1<int> >(Class1<int>(3));
    auto obj2  = Class2<int, Class3<float, int> >(Class3<float, int>(0, 1.1));
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation error:

```
error: template argument 2 is invalid
  static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<T, std::decltype(U.getGG())>;
```

Comment: It's `decltype`, not `std::decltype`. It is a language feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `std::declval`.

```
template <class T, class U>
struct hasProperMethodReturnValueType
  : std::is_same<T, decltype(std::declval<U>().getGG())>
{};
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/iWUCOyssN3sVo2yH

Answer (score 1):

In `std::decltype(U.getGG())`, `U` is a type, while `getGG` is a member function. `U.getGG()` is simply invalid syntax - you need to "create" an instance of `U` to call the member function - `std::declval` is an utility that does that for you in unevaluated contexts. Also `std::decltype` does not exist - `decltype` is a keyword.

```
decltype(std::declval<U>().getGG())
```